# Ionic 5 Web App Chrome CSS Issues (sc-ion class added)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

We ran ionic build --prod for an Ionic Angular project to generate the www folder on a Debian 10 server. Set up the domain and everything works properly.

The problem is that when opening the app in Chrome and sometimes in Safari as well on desktop, the icons, buttons and some other elements don’t show up the same as on localhost when testing with ionic serve. Specifically, a new class is added to some elements “sc-ion” that causes problems in the UI (e.g. the icons don’t have the right line-height, the buttons’ text has a different color, etc.). Please see below some screenshots.

Do you know how we can remove the sc-ion class and keep the styling consistent with what gets displayed with ionic serve on localhost? I look forward to hearing your feedback.

Thanks for your help,
Andy

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some additional information. If I refresh the page the sc-ion classes disappear and the elements look right so it happens just the first time I access the app. (I've tested this in incognito).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hotjar was causing the issues.